# The content retrieved into a div is pushing the page down instead of showing the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

hey guys after working on the script, im facing a problem where im fetching the data from another php page through ajax.  Show_msg is the div which is in the center of the page where the messages from the database fetched via AJAX are to be shown. So, the data is fetched by another php page, and then displayed in the div show_msg. The div should show the scrollbar as there are alot of messages, but unfortunately when the data is shown in the div show_msg its pushing all the page content down
like this
[image]
here is my div where the data is to be shown..

```
    <div id="show_msg">

    </div>
```

Here is my css :

```
#show_msg {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #D8D4D4;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    min-height: calc(96% -  4%);
    height: calc(96% - 4%);
    max-height: calc(96% - 4%);
}
```

Here is my JS :

```
$('#send_btn').click(function(){
    var msgContent = $('#message_input').val();
    if(msgContent == '')
    {
        alert('message to likh bhai');
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'lib/function.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{func: 'send_msg', msgContent:msgContent},
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data == 'sent')
                {
                    $('#message_input').val('');
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Here is my php page from where data is getting fetched :

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    global $con;
    $get_data = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM messages");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_data))
    {
    ?>
            <div id="chat_box">
                <img src="images/user.jpg" id="onio_user_2"  style="border: 2px solid lightblue">
                    <div class="content-2">
                        <p style="font-weight: bold;font-size:13px;">BaTuTa</p>
                        <p class="comment"><span><?php echo $row['message_body'] ?> </span></p>                     
                        </div>
            </div>
            <?php
    }
                        ?>
```

Comment: Although the question is hard to understand, have you tried `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: Yes I did but still it ain't working

Answer (score 0):

`height: calc(96% - 4%);` defines the height in percent of the containing block. If the containing block's height is not fixed it will be the height of the whole document.

You have to fix the height in `px` and add `overflow` to prevent pushing all the page content down.

```
#show_msg {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #D8D4D4;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;   
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```